# Arguments corrupted on passing in to function?

Tags: c, pointers, linker, solaris, calling-convention

I'm seeing something that's got me stumped. Maybe you folks can advise.

What appears to be a valid arguments are getting corrupted when passed to a different function.

Here is my setup:

- LibA.a
- LibB.a
- SampleApp
- MyApp.c

The bad function call is going from LibA in to LibB.

LibA, LibB and SampleApp have all been pre-complied (thankfully in debug mode) by an older version of Sun Studio on Solaris x86/64. SampleApp uses both LibA and LibB and runs just fine on my system.

MyApp uses both LibA and LibB in a manner similar to SampleApp. Yet, MyApp crashes due to this pointer corruption.

```
// File scoped string declared
static const char myString[] = "SomeText"

// The function call looks like  
libAfunc(myString, myIntVar)

// The called function prototype is like 
int libAfunc(const char* strArg, int intArg)
```

When single stepping the code, I see the pointer in the caller (`myString`) being valid and being passed as a parameter. In the callee, the address in the passed-in parameter pointer (`strArg`) is simply wrong.  In fact, all the parameters are actually wrong after passing in.

Note: The caller is in the pre-compiled LibA and the callee is in the pre-compiled LibB. I'm never even touching that code since it's all pre-compiled. Further, the code itself is probobly correct since SampleApp uses those functions, and runs fine.  (Although the call sequence could be slightly different...)

I'm thinking that my error is in the linking stage, but I'm not sure what it could be.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Is the integer parameter passed correctly?

Comment: Maybe it's a size issue ... in your app, `sizeof (char*) != sizeof (int)`, but the libraries (wrongly) assume they're the same. Try compiling as 32-bits.

Comment: @Oli: No, it is not.  I thought it was, but after sanity checking the value again, I see it's also way off.

Comment: @nonot1: Ok.  Perhaps you could simplify/clarify your question then?  The fact that we're talking about a pointer sounds like a red herring.

Comment: @Oli Good point.  Question updated to reflect all the args being wrong.

Comment: @pmg I everything is 64-bit.  Why do you say the libs might assume `sizeof (char*) == sizeof (int)`?

Comment: I was just trying a possible explanation: your program would put 8+4 bytes in the stack, but the library would read 4+4. If everything is 64-bit though, I think my point is moot.

Comment: I understand that you link against the two libraries as they are given by a third party? Are these compiled with debugging? Otherwise your debugger might just not show things correctly, there.

Comment: @nonot1: what platform is this? If it is Windows, do the calling conventions match? If not, forget that. If it is, say, Solaris, it could be something like http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19455-01/806-0477/chapter3-56/index.html. Don't know if there are different calling conventions on other platforms.

Comment: In the callee, does the address passed in appear in one of the CPU registers, or somewhere higher up or lower on the stack? Do you see the bit pattern (the hex pattern) anywhere?

Comment: @Rudy This is on Solaris. Can the Calling Convention be affected by the linker?  I'll take a closer look at the registers and stack tomorrow.

Comment: @nonot1: I doubt the calling convention can be affected by the linker, since a different calling convention usually causes different code to be generated, and that is what the compiler does, not the linker. But I don't know if this is the case on Solaris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you compile SimpleApp with your compiler? Does it still work?

I'm not familiar with your particular platform, but there was a time with some compilers where pointers could be different sizes depending upon the compiler options used.

If your compiler was producing (say) 64 bit pointers and the libs were using 32 bit pointers then your symptoms make sense.

Comment: I don't think Solaris linker can link 32-bit libraries against 64-bit code and vice versa.

Comment: Linux linker certainly can't.